# Sass variable inside mixing include

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm trying to create an each loop that creates a class name and calls a mixin with that name as the parameter. The idea is that I can make a list:

```
$list: (item1, item2, item3, ect);
```

Then run an each loop to create a class using that name and call a mixin with that name as the parameter.

```
@each $name in $list {
    .#{$name} {
        @include mixin($name);
    }
}
```

That parameter in the mixin calls another variable of the same name to set the attributes I need within the mixin. This seems like something I should be able to do but can't seem to figure out how to make the mixin parameter as a variable instead of just a string of text. Do I have to use interpolation in a specific way to be able to add the $ in front of the list name? Doing this doesn't seem to work:

```
@include mixin($#{$name});
```

What I need it to do is use the values of item1, item2, item3, ect to create the class name but then send them as variables $item1, $item2, $item3 through the mixin
and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: why do you need variables to spit each out?, that is what maps with properties/values are for,

Comment: I was trying to use grunt spritesmith but if I have it create a scss file for me it doesn't print out the css styles for each icon in the sprite like it does if you have it create a css file. So I was trying to make an each loop that I could have it print out the class name and call that sprite mixin that takes that same name as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Using just the variable name `$name` as you did the first time will work.

[Here is an example I made using your code](https://codepen.io/leemcd56/pen/LRavKV/).

Comment: This example is sending the value through the mixin. What I need is to send a variable through the mixin. I would need to send variables $red, $green, and $yellow. Not the values 'red', 'green', and 'yellow.'

Comment: nice choice of colours

Comment: @user23339729 If you want to display variable names then $colors: (red: '$red', green: '$green', yellow: '$yellow'); or else I don't understand your logic